# Hook into all password resets in Wordpress and get password before hashing?

Tags: php, functions, hooks, actions, password

I'm syncing my Wordpress authentication system with an secondary/external authentication system and my site has at least two ways of resetting the password, including:

1. *Password reset email*
2. *User account screen password reset*

There may be some third way I'm not recalling, as I've disallowed password resets thus far due to my inability to sync the systems.

**The crux of my question:** How can I hook into the password reset prior to hashing so that I can simultaneously set the new password on the secondary/external authentication system?

---

**Non-essential additional info:**

- *User resets password when using password reset email, not auto-generated*
- *User account screen is not the Wordpress dashboard, but a plugin implementation*

The two systems using different hashing mechanisms, so a post-hashing hook won't help. I know, it's inconvenient, but it's what I've got.

I can see ways to perhaps do it on a per form/method basis, but this would be really miserable to maintain as the platform grows.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`password_reset`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/password_reset/) hook.

```
function wpse_password_reset( $user, $new_pass ) {
  //* Do something useful with $new_pass
}
add_action( 'password_reset', 'wpse_password_reset', 10, 2 );
```

Edited to add after the comment:

> Looks like the reason I can't use that is that the plugin uses wp_update_user to set the new password. Is there any way I can intercept the password prior to this?

Yes. You can use the `send_password_change_email` filter.

```
function wpse_send_password_change_email( $true, $user, $userdata ) {
  //* Do something useful with the new password
  wp_die(
    sprintf(
      '%1$s changed their password to %2$s.',
      $userdata[ 'user_login' ],
      $_POST[ 'pass1' ]
    )
  );

  //* Need to return $true since it's a filter
  return $true;
}
add_filter( 'send_password_change_email', 'wpse_send_password_change_email', 10, 3 );
```

Comment: That's what I first tried, but it only seems to fire if you use a reset email. Setting a new password isn't caught by that as best as I can tell.

Comment: Looks like the reason I can't use that is that the plugin uses `wp_update_user` to set the new password. Is there any way I can intercept the password prior to this?